# Manual upgrade of Android Plug in on IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ Platform, and use a not up to date version of it, can we upgrade the plug-in on IntelliJ using the one located at AS? Example AS 2.0 will ship with IDEA 15, and IDEA 16 with Android plug in 1.5